# Insert Xml at Specific Node SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following Code,

```
@MasterXML= '
    <Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
      <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="'+@Datasetname+'">
          <Query>
          </Query>
          <Fields>
          <Field>
          </Field>
          </Fields>
        </DataSet>
      </DataSets>
      </Report> '
    WHILE @i <= @Cnt
    BEGIN

    Select @xml=
     (  
      SELECT  @cname AS [@Name]
               ,@cname AS [DataField]
               ,'System.String' AS [rd:TypeName]
        FOR XML PATH('Field')
    );
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @MasterXML.modify(' insert sql:variable("@xml") as last into  (Fields)[1] ' )  
    end
    select @MasterXML
```

I am Generating a XMLat @xml through loop and i want to insert it after

I tried  `SET @MasterXML.modify(' insert sql:variable("@xml") as last into  (Fields)[1] ' )`, but the generated fields does not add up.

Can Anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that this can be done much better... You do not tell us, where the `@cname` is coming from, but this can be done without any loop or `.modify()` - at least I think so... My suggestion: There are some answers upon this question. If they solve it, please accept the one you like most and use your right to vote. Then set up a new question with some more information what you really try to achieve. This sounds like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@MasterXML` has a default namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition` so you need to reference the nodes using that namespace.

```
set @MasterXML.modify('
  declare default element namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition";
  insert sql:variable("@xml") as last into  (/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Fields)[1]');
```

Note that the elements in the XML you are adding to `@MasterXML` does not use a namespace so you will get `xmlns=""` added for you for those elements. If you want them to be part of the same namespace you have to specify that in your `for xml` query.

[Add Namespaces to Queries with WITH XMLNAMESPACES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces)

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression isn't valid. try something like this:

```
SET @MasterXML.modify(' insert sql:variable("@xml") as last into  (/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Fields)[1] ' )
```

Comment: What do you mean "the fields does not add up"?

Comment: The @XML part does not adds up to specified node.